# unix script to convert unsigned int32 to big endian bytes and write to file

Tags: bash, awk, byte, endianness

I want to write a script (bash/awk/gawk/any other standard script) on a unix machine that has an unsigned integer as  program argument, it then converts it into big endian and write bytes to a new file.

Something like this:
./writebytes 5 outputfile.txt
where 5 is the value I want to write to outputfile.txt in bytes after converting to big endian

now if I do 
hexdump outputfile.txt
the output should look like

```
0000000 0005 0000
0000004
```

I am very new to unix and scripting.
I then want to be able to output the contents of outputfile.txt in simple decimal human-readable format.

```
./readbytes outputfile.txt
```

and the output is 5

Comment: Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Your hexdump shows a little-endian representation, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning an ascii representation of an integer into a binary 32 bit big endian integer is easy with perl, as already noted, and saving that value to a file is simple shell redirection:

```
$ num=5
$ perl -e "print pack('N', $num)" > outputfile.txt
$ xxd outputfile.txt
00000000: 0000 0005
```

Notes:

- The replacement of the variable `$num` is done by the shell in this example, not by perl itself.
- `pack("N", value)` is the perl way to convert `value` to a 32 bit big endian integer.

For the sake of completeness, a little-endian version is:

```
$ perl -e 'print pack("V", 5)' | xxd
00000000: 0500 0000
```

Reading back from the file is a bit more complicated, since it's binary data, not line-oriented text. You have to read all 4 bytes of the file at once no matter what they are. Luckily perl makes that easy too:

```
$ perl -0777 -nE 'say unpack("N", $_)' outputfile.txt
5
```

The `-0777` argument is the idiomatic way to read an entire file at once when combined with `-n`, which reads files or standard input, invoking the rest of the script (Provided by `-E`) on each chunk (Normally a line, but the entire file in this case)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Perl one-liner, I think you are looking for something like below

```
$ hexdump <(perl -e ' $x=pack("I",5) ; print $x ')
0000000 0005 0000
0000004
```

if you want to get as parameter

```
$ data=5
$ perl -ne ' $x=pack("I",$_) ; print $x '  <<< "$data" > outfile.txt

$ hexdump outfile.txt
0000000 0005 0000
0000004

$ wc outfile.txt
0 0 4 outfile.txt
```

To read it back the outfile.txt, again you can use Perl

```
$ perl -ne ' $a=unpack("I",$_); print $a ' outfile.txt
5
```

Comment: Using `N` as the pack format is a better choice than `I`. The former is explicitly an unsigned 32 bit integer in big endian. The latter is a native C `int`, which may or may not be big endian and might not even be 32 bits (But granted probably is on any hardware OP is likely to be using). So: `perl -e 'print pack("N", 5)' > outfile.txt`

Comment: Your code for reading a number back from a file will also have problems if one of the bytes is `0x0A`. See my answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `gawk`, here's a strange way to get those big-endian bytes without manually doing divisions and modulos :

```
echo 3496432627 |
```

---

```
gawk -b '{ system(gensub("[0-9A-F]{2}", "\\\\x&", "g", 
                 sprintf(" printf $\47%.8X\47", $_))) }'
```

---

```
?gS?
```

---

```
| god --endian=big -t u4

0000000 3496432627
0000004
```